# SAWarning: Could not instantiate type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER'> when I use sqlalchemy and pd.io.sql.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I try to read pandas DataFrame from my SQLite table. When I run the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

dbname = "sqlite:////Users/leda/home/Magnetic_stars/SQLite/Magnetic_stars.sqlite"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(dbname)
res = pd.io.sql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Resolved;", engine)
```

I get SAWarning:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py:860: SAWarning: Could not instantiate type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER'> with reflected arguments [u'4']; using no arguments.
 coltype = self._resolve_type_affinity(type_)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py:860: SAWarning: Could not instantiate type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER'> with reflected arguments [u'2']; using no arguments.
 coltype = self._resolve_type_affinity(type_)
```

see my [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7380) for more details.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: Could you try the following?
1. Run your script with debugger: python -m pdb ./script.py
2. In debugger console execute 'b sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py:913, coltype == sqltypes.INTEGER' (without quotes)
3. Press c for a debugger to run your program
4. Execution should stop at line 913 in base.py - see what is the value of variable type_ (e.g. by 'print type_')

Comment: @zifot, sorry for my delay with answer. I get INT(4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so looking at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7380) it seems like your problem is solved. For the record, let me just shortly summarize what happend.

As we know from [#7396](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7396), pandas is introspecting *all* the tables per *every* read_sql_table call.

Another thing is that your database contains a table with a column of a type reported by sqlite as "INT(4)".

SqlAlchemy (which is used by pandas under the hood) sqlite dialect  [interprets the "(4)" part as an argument to be passed to its type constructor](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_0_9_4/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py#L915). But constructor of [sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_0_9_4/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py#L1445) doesn't take any arguments and that [causes a warning](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_0_9_4/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py#L917) and effectively ignoring these arguments, treating INT(4) as INT.